# Swift - Deeplink within app to launch popup viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, deep-linking

I'm trying to launch a deeplink from within a Label in Swift, the intention is that the deeplink launches a popup view controller with some additional information, these deeplinks will not be available externally in the app.

I have followed the following youtube video to setup the new view controller, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgCIRMz_3dE, but the example here is on a button click, and i would like this to be dynamic as the content is driven from a database, i was hoping to use the following (https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) to dyanmically add deeplinks into various words within a label.

The part i'm stuck on is how to convert the following snippet of code, into a format that can be run when the deeplink is selected, my understanding is this needs to be executed within the app delegate.

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController
    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Can anybody help here?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't quite understand your question. Can you elaborate it a little more?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, let me try and explain a little further.

I am using the TTTAttributedLabel plugin above to assign hyperlinks dynamically to text pull from a database into a label.

These links are deeplinks, i.e. deeplink://hyperlink name

what i am looking for is a way to use this deeplinks to show a popup view controller with some additional information, the video above shows how to do this on a button, but i need to this to work via a deeplink, so as far as i know i need to do this through the appdelegate, what im looking to find out is, if the code can be used in appdelegate

Answer (score 0):

please rewrite in plain english with more details, but anyway is a bit obscure why use a deep link to "show a popup view controller with some additional information".
Passing info between controllers via deep links (custom URL is the correct name..) is wrong.
iOS is not web based.
So read other stackoverflow detailed answers to get the right approach.